# Removing Objects (Account) from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public boolean removeAccount (String accountNumber)
{
    int index = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (index < accounts.size() && !found)
    {
        if ( accounts.get(index).getAccountNumber().equals(accountNumber))
        {
            found = true;
            accounts.remove(accountNumber);
        }
        else
            index++;
    }
    if (found == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

When I enter a correct account number it returns true, however it doesn't remove the account from the ArrayList, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: accounts.remove(index)... remove the object by the index position

Comment: Note : The block after the `while` loop can be replaced with `return found;`.

Answer (score 1):

There are [two `remove` methods for `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-).  One takes the index, and the other takes the object to remove itself.  But you have supplied the account number, not the index or the account itself.  The account number is not in the list, the account is, so the account number is not removed.

You have the index, supply it instead of the account number.

```
accounts.remove(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument you're using is actually [`List#remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)).  You're attempting to remove a `String` from your list, which is most definitely not present.

Use the `int` parameter instead:

```
accounts.remove(index);
```